# Build a project targeting MSVC on linux Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, visual-c++, archlinux

I have a private server that I've been slowly setting up for personal projects, but I've run into a bit of a roadblock. My server is running Arch linux [I like bleeding edge and minimalistic installs in situations like this] and I have Jenkins running on it so that I can have it automatically build projects. I have a project that I've been working on that is currently targeting the Win32/64 platform using MSVC, but I can't seem to find any info anywhere about setting up a job on Jenkins for this situation. I was hoping that I could maybe setup a Docker instance that would be able to provide the MSVC toolchain, especially since Visual Studio Code is available for Linux, and that I could use that as part of my Jenkins setup to generate Win binaries for me to test on my main machine. I mention this because naturally, Visual Studio is not a command line utility, and currently my server is a pure headless setup that only provides cli interaction, so if possible, I would like to avoid directly adding GUI packages to the server, but if it is the only way, I'd be willing to do so. Is there really no way to achieve what I'm going for with this?

Sorry if this lacks important details or is formatted poorly, this is my first time asking a question here as it's very rare for me to not be able to find the info I'm looking for in an already existing question.

Comment: `Visual Studio is not a command line utility` This isn't correct. The compiler used by the Visual Studio IDE can easily be used on the command line, we do it every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, this is not currently possible as it stems from a misunderstanding of exactly what docker provides. Docker simply uses the underlying OS to provide everything and does not provide any virtualization of foreign OSs. Without a version of the MSVC toolchain that can run on linux, or possibly the use of WINE, there is not a way to achieve this short of a VM. Since WINE is not perfect, the most reliable solution as it appears to me is the VM, but YMMV. The other advantage to using a VM is that I can keep the server headless.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer this question completely, but this topic is interesting to me too.

**Note:** Visual Studio Code is open-source, but that's an Electron-based editor. Visual Studio IDE and MSVC are proprietary Windows-only apps.

---

The website https://blog.sixeyed.com/how-to-dockerize-windows-applications/ suggests it's possible to dockerize Windows apps, including Visual Studio.

> Docker images for Windows apps need to be based on microsoft/nanoserver or microsoft/windowsservercore, or on another image based on one of those.

Once you get that working, I'd use Visual Studio command-line builds, like `devenv /build file.sln [optionally /project file.vcxproj ]`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2017 ).

---

Note that the VS2017 installer does not function on Wine. I recently filed a bug for this (https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45749 followed by https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45757 ).

---

I personally use Appveyor for auto-building MSVC apps. Appveyor is a Windows-based centralized cloud service, not a self-hosted CI system.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the link for dockerizing the windows apps, but it seems that the tutorial implicity expects one to be running Docker on a Windows host. I'm still looking into it, but so far I've not found anything. It's looking more and more like I would need to run a virtual machine on it, which I would very much like to avoid. I haven't checked out Appveyor yet, if it is a linux based app, it may do what I need, though I'll be pretty hesitant depending on how it achieves that.

Comment: appveyor is a windows-based hosted cloud service, not an installable CI system.